# Как правильно написать название чертежа?

Tags: склонение

"Шпунтовое ограждение котлована опор 2, 3, 4" или "шпунтовое ограждение котлована опоры 2, 3, 4"?

Comment: "..опор "2", "3","4"." или №2, 3, 4 вместо "2", или "опор с номерами 2, 3, ..."

Answer (score 1):

«Шпунтовое ограждение котлована опор 2, 3, 4» можно оставить без изменений, хотя количественное несоответствие несколько смущает. Есть варианты...

Шпунтовое ограждение котлованов опор 2, 3, 4.

Шпунтовое ограждение котлованов под опоры 2, 3, 4.

Шпунтовые ограждения котлованов под опоры 2 — 4.